# How to run each line using F8?

Tags: vba, ms-access

How to you run a Private Sub, and execute each line?

It is not allowing me to Step into by pressing F8.

```vb
Private Sub upload_fed_expenses_batch()
    
    Dim dbConn As ADODB.Connection, sSQL As String, rsLocal As New ADODB.Recordset, rstmp As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dbOracle As New ADODB.Connection, rsOracle As New ADODB.Recordset, lCount As Long, rsValue As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dAmount As Double, dBase As Double

    Stop
```

Comment: put a break on each line and press F5, by the way, there's nothing on your code to step into anyway.

Comment: break points doesn't work on declarations.

Comment: Rolled back the edit.  The answer you accepted doesn't make any sense without the original code.

Comment: And questions without code are somewhat verboten anyway, @Comintern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Step into* only works on *executable instructions*.

`Dim` statements aren't executable; their order doesn't matter at all actually - essentially, a local variable comes into existence as soon as execution enters its scope*, regardless of where in that scope it's declared.

So in this case when execution enters the `upload_fed_expenses_batch` procedure, it hits the first executable statement and, because that's a `Stop` statement, stops right there and then.

**From that point on**, you can use F8 to run *executable* code line by line, but as was accurately mentioned in comments already, you can't break on declarations.

---

*with a caveat for `Static` locals.